# Return results to parent process using joblib

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, joblib

I am running a function which takes a while to be evaluated 16 times. However, all these runs are independent on each other. Therefore I decided to speed it up using joblib.

Joblib works just like it should and speeds it up, but I'm struggling with one problem - how to return the evaluated value properly? I want to save the 16 results into memory, ideally into a list. However, using a global variable does not seem to be an option as a new Python process doesn't use the global variables the parent does. According to joblib documentation, max_nbytes argument of Parallel puts a threshold on array size to share, yet all changes I did to the list of 16 integers in the child process functions had no effect on the list in parent process.

Is the only option saving the calculated values to files and then retrieving them afterwards using the parent process or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need joblib, you could put your results in a `Queue` and retrieve your results at the end. 
[from multiprocessing documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print q.get()    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

You could also use `multiprocessing.Pool`, which does exactly that: ([from multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction))

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

will print to standard output:

> [1, 4, 9]